# Combine two SQL queries in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

On the SMC platform, we employ two SQL queries to fetch data pertaining to a specific column. We pull data from two tables in the Data Extension. However, when attempting to merge these two queries into a single query, we encounter an issue as we receive no results. There are no syntax errors in the code, and the code runs perfectly fine on the platform.
Could you kindly assist in pinpointing where I might be making an error in the code?
Here is the separated code using the UNION function:

```sql
SELECT
    T.Id,
    A.Name,
    A.LastName,
    A.Email,
    A.Country,
    A.MiddleName,
    A.CreatedDate
FROM
    [Data_Extension_1] T
INNER JOIN
    New_table A
ON
    T.Id = A.Id

UNION

SELECT
    B.Id,
    C.Name,
    C.LastName,
    C.PersonEmail
FROM
    [Data_Extension_1] B
INNER JOIN
    Common_table C
ON
    B.Id = C.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't receive an error, but using `UNION` in your SQL, requires both queries which are combined, should have the same columns.

It is difficult to see, what your goal is, when looking at the above query, but it indeed looks like `UNION` is not the right way to go. You should probably be looking into joining all of the tables, using either `LEFT` or `RIGHT JOIN`, in order to allow for records not having related records in all the data extensions queried.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you foe the answer.

Comment: My main objective was to merge the two queries, and after attempting to use UNION, I see that it might not be the ideal approach since UNION typically requires matching column structures. I will try another ways then, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In UNION, just make sure you enforce the same fieldnames and the same order in all queries.

I see not much wrong with setting values empty in your second one?
Clearly, both your tables fundamentally contain the same kind of data (recipients).

So the second field list would need to be `C.PersonEmail AS email, '' AS Country, '' AS MiddleName, '' AS createdDate`

```
SELECT
    T.Id,
    A.Name,
    A.LastName,
    A.Email,
    A.Country,
    A.MiddleName,
    A.CreatedDate
FROM
    [Data_Extension_1] T
INNER JOIN
    New_table A
ON
    T.Id = A.Id

UNION

SELECT
    B.Id
    ,C.Name
    ,C.LastName

,C.PersonEmail AS Email
, '' AS Country
, '' AS MiddleName
, '' AS CreatedDate

FROM
    [Data_Extension_1] B
INNER JOIN
    Common_table C
ON
    B.Id = C.Id
```

Just - as always - ensure in any follow up code that empty values are handled in relevant fields. But empty values might occur also in DE 1 alone, this is not in any way caused by the UNION. It's just 100% sure now.

To reiterate, I see nothing wrong with "filling up".